# Change specific name in list

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I change an account name all the accounts names in the list are changing simultaneously. How can change specific name.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of accountList; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <input *ngIf="edit" autocomplete="off" matInput type="tel" class="form-control" maxlength="16"
            minlength="10" placeholder="Account 1" [(ngModel)]="accountNickname">
        <div class="fw-500 font-20 black" *ngIf="nameUpdate">Account {{i + 1}}
        <span><img src="../../assets/icon/edit.png" class="edit-icon" (click)="editIcon(item, i)"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fw-400 mt-10 black">{{item.accountDetail}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: share code of TS file

Comment: Please go through the Angular Template Driven Form [guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms) first. You're binding a single variable `accountNickname` for all the elements in the `accountList` array. Ideally it must be something like `[(ngModel)]="item?.accountNickname"` where each element in the array gets bound to it's own property.

Answer (score 0):

you are using accountNickname variable from TS to bind.

you should bind which name is there in the array.

```
<input *ngIf="edit" autocomplete="off" matInput type="tel" class="form-control" maxlength="16"
minlength="10" [placeholder]="'Account ' + i" [(ngModel)]="item.accountNickname">
```

above in ngModel it should be `item.accountNickname`

Comment: its working, but when I click the edit icon it goes into edit mode for all the items in list.